# Pandas conditional join

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a df like the one below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [1,2], [2,2], [3,2]], columns = ['Var1', 'Var2'])

Var1    Var2
1       1
2       1
3       1
1       2
2       2
3       2
```

I would like to merge the df on itself and create a new variable. In SQL I would achieve it by the following statement

```
 a.*
,b.var2 as Var3
from df as a
left join
df as b
on a.var1 = b.var1 and a.var2+1 = b.var2
```

To achieve the following result

```
Var1    Var2    Var3
1       1       2
2       1       2
3       1       2
1       2   
2       2   
3       2
```

When trying to do this in pandas I use the following statement

```
df['Var3'] = df.merge(df['Var2'], how='left', left_on=['Var1', 'Var2'+1], right_on=['Var1', 'Var2'])
```

However it throws the error below at me as it thinks that I want to concatenate the 'Var2' rather than adding on +1 to it.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

How do I go about achieving this conditional join on a dataframe in pandas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Var3'] = df.assign(tmp=df['Var2']+1).merge(df, how='left', left_on=['Var1', 'tmp'], right_on=['Var1', 'Var2'])['Var2_y']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Var1  Var2  Var3
0     1     1   2.0
1     2     1   2.0
2     3     1   2.0
3     1     2   NaN
4     2     2   NaN
5     3     2   NaN
```

`df.assign(tmp=df['Var2']+1)` creates a temporary column containing all the values of the `Var2` incremented by one. You can't do `let_on=['Var1', 'Var2' + 1]` in Python, so you can use the `assign` trick instead.

Explanation for `Var2_y`:

The intermediate dataframe freshly after merging looks like this:

```
>>> df.assign(tmp=df['Var2']+1).merge(df, how='left', left_on=['Var1', 'tmp'], right_on=['Var1', 'Var2'])
   Var1  Var2_x  tmp  Var2_y
0     1       1    2     2.0
1     2       1    2     2.0
2     3       1    2     2.0
3     1       2    3     NaN
4     2       2    3     NaN
5     3       2    3     NaN
```

Some columns are already existing, so instead of overwriting them, pandas renames the new columns to `_x` and `_y`. The column we want is the `Var2_y` one, so that's the one we select.